# how to use extraPackages options for code-server on NixOS

Tags: nixos, code-server

Decided to install code-server. Installation proccess was simple, but a lot of packages are missing on terminal. Later I found an option `services.code-server.extraPackages`. Why does it exist? I expected that all packages, including `sudo`, will be available in PATH. Instead it is required to specify packages manualy.

So what is the reasoning to have `extraPackages` options? If I have hundreds of packages inside `environment.systemPackages` do I have to repeat it for code-server?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a consequence of how systemd services work on NixOS; they have a rather minimal `PATH` by default.

What you could do is add to the systemd options directly.

```hs
{ config, lib, pkgs, ... }:
{
  # ...

  systemd.services.code-server.path = [
    "/run/current-system/sw/bin"
    "/run/wrappers/bin"
  ];
}
```

I believe this should do the job.

If it does, you could make a PR to add this behavior as an option if you like.

Comment: when I am using `services.code-server.extraPackages = config.environment.systemPackages` nixos-rebuild complains about 
`error: infinite recursion encountered, at /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/lib/modules.nix:
753:14`

Comment: I've removed that option from my answer is it clearly does not apply in this situation.